# Custom pager link text with Cycle2

Tags: jquery, slideshow

This question is about customizing the links of the pager in malsup's cycle2 jquery plugin as per the demo here: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/demo/pager.php. I'm trying to pass the alt attribute of the slide to the pager template but can't figure out how. The standard method which consists in using the slide's number with {{slideNum}} works fine if you're satisfied with the slide's number (1, 2, 3, etc) as only text in the pager's link. However I neee to customize that content. I'd be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually opted for Bootstrap Carousel which is better suited for customization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any attribute of the slide. {{alt}} would work just fine. See code below:

```
data-cycle-pager-template="<a href="#" ><img src='{{src}}' width=20 height=20></a>"
```

This link on the JQuery Cycle page has the documentation you're looking for:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/pager.php